# Result vary after different "leave one group out" together with MLSMOTE package

Tags: cross-validation

I am quite confused with the leave one group out, since my data is highly skewed, I use MLSMOTE from https://github.com/phiyodr/multilabel-oversampling,
below is my code:

```
### using sklearn cv function
groups = np.array(mo_Combined_4Courses_sampled.index)
# groups.size
logo = LeaveOneGroupOut()
logo.get_n_splits(groups=groups)

pipelines ={
            'scaledLR': Pipeline([('scaled' , StandardScaler()),('LR' , MultiOutputClassifier(LogisticRegression(random_state = 0)))]),\
            'scaledMNB': Pipeline([('scaled' , StandardScaler()),('MNB' , MultiOutputClassifier(GaussianNB()))]),\
            # 'scaledKNN': Pipeline([('scaled' , StandardScaler()),('KNN' , MultiOutputClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier()))]),\
            'scaledDT': Pipeline([('scaled' , StandardScaler()),('DT' , MultiOutputClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 0)))]),\
            'scaledXGB': Pipeline([('scaled' , StandardScaler()),('XGB' , MultiOutputClassifier(XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic', random_state = 0, n_jobs = -1)))]),\
            # 'scaledSVC': Pipeline([('scaled' , StandardScaler()),('SVC' , MultiOutputClassifier(SVC(random_state = 0, probability=True)))]),\
            'scaledRF': Pipeline([('scaled', StandardScaler()),('RF', MultiOutputClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)))])
           }

model_name = []
results = []
for pipe, model in pipelines.items():
    # print(pipe, model)
    now = datetime.now()
    print(f"Time for {pipe} is {now}")
    scoring = ['accuracy', 'recall_macro', 'precision_macro', 'neg_mean_squared_error', 'f1_macro']
    scores4 = cross_validate(model, mo_Combined_4Courses_sampled.iloc[:,:-4], mo_Combined_4Courses_sampled.iloc[:,-4:], cv=logo.split(mo_Combined_4Courses_sampled.iloc[:,:-4], mo_Combined_4Courses_sampled.iloc[:,-4:], groups), scoring=scoring, groups=groups, return_train_score=False)
    # results[pipe] = crossv_results
    accuracy_scores4 = scores4['test_accuracy']
    recall_scores4 = scores4['test_recall_macro']
    precision_scores4 = scores4['test_precision_macro']
    mse_scores4 = scores4['test_neg_mean_squared_error']
    rmse_scores4 = [np.sqrt(abs(x)) for x in mse_scores4]
    f1_scores4 = scores4['test_f1_macro']

    final_accuracy4 = np.mean(accuracy_scores4)
    final_recall4 = np.mean(recall_scores4)
    final_precision4 = np.mean(precision_scores4)
    final_mse4 = np.mean(mse_scores4)
    final_rmse4 = np.mean(rmse_scores4)
    final_f14 = np.mean(f1_scores4)
    metrics = [final_recall4,final_f14,final_precision4,abs(final_mse4),final_rmse4,final_accuracy4]
    score = pd.DataFrame(metrics)
    score = score.rename({0:'Recall',1:'F1',2:'Precision',3:'MSE',4:'RMSE',5:"Accuracy"})
    displayed_score = score.T
    results.append(metrics)
    model_name.append(pipe)
    print(f"4-labels_{pipe}_sk_LOGO_MLSMOTE: \n {displayed_score}")
    now = datetime.now()
    print(f"Time for {pipe} is {now}")
```

```
### using for loop to select one group out
pipelines ={
            'scaledLR_w_MLSMOTE_manual_LOGO': Pipeline([('scaled' , StandardScaler()),('LR' , MultiOutputClassifier(LogisticRegression(random_state = 0)))]),\
            'scaledMNB_w_MLSMOTE_manual_LOGO': Pipeline([('scaled' , StandardScaler()),('MNB' , MultiOutputClassifier(GaussianNB()))]),\
            'scaledDT_w_MLSMOTE_manual_LOGO': Pipeline([('scaled' , StandardScaler()),('DT' , MultiOutputClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 0)))]),\
            'scaledXGB_w_MLSMOTE_manual_LOGO': Pipeline([('scaled' , StandardScaler()),('XGB' , MultiOutputClassifier(XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic', random_state = 0, n_jobs = -1)))]),\
            'scaledRF_w_MLSMOTE_manual_LOGO': Pipeline([('scaled', StandardScaler()),('RF', MultiOutputClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)))]),\
           # 'scaledSVC_w_MLSMOTE_manual_LOGO': Pipeline([('scaled' , StandardScaler()),('SVC' , MultiOutputClassifier(SVC(random_state = 0, probability=True)))]),\
            # 'scaledKNN_w_MLSMOTE_manual_LOGO': Pipeline([('scaled' , StandardScaler()),('KNN' , MultiOutputClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier()))])
           }


#10% dataset 4-labels
train_com_x = mo_Combined_4Courses_sampled.iloc[:,:-4].reset_index()
train_com_y = mo_Combined_4Courses_sampled.iloc[:,-4:].reset_index()

com_y_true = []
com_y_pred = []
com_mean = []
com_probs = []
predict_A08 = []
predict_A53 = []

for model_name, clf in pipelines.items():
    now = datetime.now()
    print(f"Time for {model_name} is {now}")
    for i, j in enumerate(list(train_com_x.groupby("StudentID").groups)):
        com_y_test = train_com_y[train_com_y['StudentID']==j].set_index('StudentID') # testing student id labels
        com_X_test = train_com_x[train_com_x['StudentID']==j].set_index('StudentID')# test student id features
        com_X_train = train_com_x[train_com_x['StudentID']!=j].set_index('StudentID') # training student IDs features
        com_y_train = train_com_y[train_com_y['StudentID']!=j].set_index('StudentID') # training student IDs features

        clf.fit(com_X_train, com_y_train)
        re08 = clf.predict(com_pre[com_pre.index=='A08']).mean(axis=0)  # predicted result:EngE,EngB
        re53 = clf.predict(com_pre[com_pre.index=='A53']).mean(axis=0)  # predicted result:EngE,EngB
        _mean = clf.score(com_X_test, com_y_test)
        predictions = clf.predict(com_X_test)
        probs = clf.predict_proba(com_X_test)
        probs = probs[:1]
        com_y_true.append(com_y_test)
        com_y_pred.append(predictions)
        com_mean.append(_mean)
        predict_A08.append(re08)
        predict_A53.append(re53)
        com_probs.append(probs)
    f1_ = []
    recall_ = []
    precision_ = []
    MSE = []
    RMSE = []
    for i in range(len(com_y_true)):
        # print(classification_report(com_y_true[i], com_y_pred[i]))
        F1 = f1_score(com_y_true[i], com_y_pred[i], average='micro')
        Precision = precision_score(com_y_true[i], com_y_pred[i], average='micro')
        Recall = recall_score(com_y_true[i], com_y_pred[i], average='micro', zero_division=0)
        mse = mean_squared_error(com_y_true[i], com_y_pred[i])
        rmse = np.sqrt(mse)
        recall_.append(Recall)
        precision_.append(Precision)
        f1_.append(F1)
        MSE.append(mse)
        RMSE.append(rmse)
    metrics = [recall_,f1_,precision_,MSE,RMSE,com_mean]
    _ = []
    for i in range(len(metrics)):
        mean = sum(metrics[i]) / len(metrics[i])
        _.append(mean)
    # print("Mean of recall_,f1_,precision_,MSE,RMSE,accuracy of Multioutput Classifier (2-class): ")
    # print("Mean of recall_,f1_,precision_,MSE,RMSE,accuracy of Multioutput Classifier: (4-class)")
    # print(_)
    score = pd.DataFrame(_)
    score = score.rename({0:'Recall',1:'F1',2:'Precision',3:'MSE',4:'RMSE',5:"Accuracy"})
    displayed_score = score.T
    print(f"4-labels_{model_name}: \n {displayed_score}")
    now = datetime.now()
    print(f"Time for {model_name} is {now}")
```

From the manual logo, my average score for Recall,F1 score and Precision are all above 0.7, but using sklearn package, my Recall,F1 score and PRecision are only around 0.3, my questions are:

1. Am I using the code correctly?
2. Am I using cross-validation correctly? I found out for cross-validation, some suggest using train set, some suggest using test set, but for leave one group out, we shouldn't separate train-test, do we?
3. Since my data is imbalanced, I use MLSMOTE for training set to do data augmentation, after the data augmentation, should I combine the augmented train set with original test set and then use the new combination for cross-validation or just use the augmented train set for cross-validation?
4. This is a question above precision-recall curve, I have a set of binary models, for the PR curve, should I predict the train probability and use the ground truth train and this predicted train result in the plot or predict test probability and use it together with test ground truth result in the plot?

Sorry my question is quite long, really hope anyone can help, appreciate your support.